# Cannot pass data to child if it is not initialized on definition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am passing an array data from parent to child component and I have encountered the following situations:

***parent.component.html:***

```
<child-component
     ...
    [options]="students"
>
</child-component>
```

**Status I:** When I set the array on definition, everything is ok and I can get the array values on the child component.

***parent.component.ts:***

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    students: any[] = [
        { name: "Mary" },
        { name: "Marta" },
        { name: "Kelly" },
        { name: "John" },
        { name: "Shelley" },
        { name: "Frankstein" },
        { name: "Shierley" },
        { name: "Igor" }
    ];
}
```

***child.component.ts:***

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() options: any[]= [];
}
```

**Status II:** However, when I set the array on a method instead of definition, I get the input value as null. Why I want to fill the array in a method is that I fill it by retrieving data from server. So, I struggled with this problem and finally found that the problem is not related to async data. It is related to this definition place. So, how can I perform the data can be passed by its array values?

***parent.component.ts:***

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    students: any[] = [];



ngOnInit() {
  this.getStudents();
}

getStudents() {
    this.students = [
        { name: "Mary" },
        { name: "Marta" },
        { name: "Kelly" },
        { name: "John" },
        { name: "Shelley" },
        { name: "Frankstein" },
        { name: "Shierley" },
        { name: "Igor" }
    ];
}
```

***Note:*** I think assigning null to the students on defining it. But otherwise it throws error and I encounter null value exception on child. Maybe lifcel-ycle related problem, but I have already tried ngOnchanges, ngAfterViewInit, etc.

Comment: Is the behaviour above normal? How should I change iti to fix the problem? Anybody else experienced on Angular?

Comment: What about getting this result inside your child component in  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) method

Answer (score 2):

If you do not directly assign an object which is passed to a child component, initially the input will receive undefined or an empty array since you are assigning an empty array to students variable.

To avoid it use conditional rendering with ngIf:

```
<child-component
     *ngIf="students && students.length > 0"
    [options]="students"
>
</child-component>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. This seems to be logical. But still the same result, it is very strange that the only difference between status I & II is set placesof the property. On the other hand, is the definition is on parent component? Do you also mean `*ngIf="students && students.length > 0"` ?

Comment: Yes it should be students, my bad. Updated my answer.

Comment: It is not just about the places of the propery, it is totally related to the component lifecycle, child components will receive undefined objects if you do not assign any value to them at initialization, since parent objects lifecycle is also dependent on the child components creation.

Comment: The scenario is that: I created a reusable autocomplete and use it in my parent component. As you know, I should pass this reusable (dumb) component data as input (or maybe using a BehaviourSubject, etc.). I am not sure if you have time, but the reusable component definition is already ready and if you try to use it in a parent component, you may test it. You can also get data from mock API and see if it works, but the problem is probably lifeceycle and I had already tried many different things. At last I will use BehaviorSubject, but for this scenerio I think there is no need to subscribe.

Comment: At option I: Could you please try to use the following approach (stackblitz is also proided) as a reusable component? https://medium.com/@mustafakunwa/mat-autocomplete-tricks-selection-on-leave-validation-c6209e45a326

Comment: Option II: Besides that, would you suggest to use BehaviourSubject for this scenario instead of @Input? But even if so, I would prefer you try to use the autocomplete in that example as a reusable component. Any help would be **really** apprteciated. Thansk in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by using autocomplete as a reusable component, article you have provided is using a directive which is working fine and totally re-usable. A BehaviorSubject is not related to this kind of implementation.

Comment: I mean that I want to use this component as a reusable implementation. For example the data and the parameters are defined on the same component, but as you know I have to define some of them in my custom component and pass the data for the list to this component (also some other parameters e.g. placeholder, ...). So, would you mind defining a custom component on that stackblits and use this component?

Comment: The problem is that: When I pass an array data in the `getEmployees()` method on that page, I can get value. However, if I use subscribe method `this.employeeService.get().subscribe((list: EmployeeDto)... {}` as on that page, I encounter null value exceptions. I also tried to use `async` on parent.html and set value like `this.employees = this.employeeService.get()`, but it does not fixed the problem. I also tried to use `ngOnChanges`, but still the same problem. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: It is the expected behavior to get null values from local variables which are later filled asynchronously, adding a simple ngIf should solve this problem without any additional implementation. If you can prepare a MRE, I can try to fix the problem.